# Testnet credentials

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, node.js

How to get testnet credentials to use bit-coin core functions in Node.js.

```
{
    "Bitcoin": {
      "testnet": {
        "username": "name",
        "password": "sdaddf",
        "network": "regtest",
        "port": 18332 
      },
      "mainnet": {
        "username": "name",
        "password": "sadasd",
        "network": "mainnet",
        "port": 8332
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set them in your bitcoin.conf file and use the network specific configuration sections. So you can add to your bitcoin.conf file:

```
[test]
rpcuser=name
rpcpassword=sdaddf
```